# Redux Store Change does not re renders Login component to redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Hi I have a login component where I call an action creator to dispatch login action and fetch user details from backend api.
Call is successful but my Login component is not re rendering and redirecting to Home. This is my login component.

```
import​ ​React​, { ​Component​ } ​from​ ​"​react​"​;
import​ { ​connect​ } ​from​ ​"​react-redux​"​;
​import​ { ​Redirect​ } ​from​ ​"​react-router-dom​"​;

​import​ { ​login​ } ​from​ ​"​../../store/actions/authActions​"​;
​import​ ​PageHead​ ​from​ ​"​../layout/PageHead​"​;

​class​ ​Login​ ​extends​ ​Component​ {
    ​constructor​(​props​) {
        ​super​(props);

        ​this​.​state​ ​=​ {
            email​:​ ​"​"​,
            password​:​ ​"​"​,
            loading​:​ ​false​
        };
        ​this​.​handleChange​ ​=​ ​this​.​handleChange​.​bind​(​this​);
        ​this​.​handleSubmit​ ​=​ ​this​.​handleSubmit​.​bind​(​this​);
        ​console​.​log​(​this​.​props​);
    }

    ​handleChange​(​e​) {
        ​this​.​setState​({ [​e​.​target​.​name​]​:​ ​e​.​target​.​value​ });
    }

    ​handleSubmit​() {
        ​event​.​preventDefault​();
        ​this​.​props​.​login​({
            email​:​ ​this​.​state​.​email​,
            password​:​ ​this​.​state​.​password​
        });
        ​this​.​setState​({ loading​:​ ​true​, email​:​ ​"​"​, password​:​ ​"​"​ });
    }

    ​render​() {
        ​if​ (​!​this​.​props​.​auth​.​is_logged​) {
            ​return​ ​<​Redirect to​=​"​/​"​ ​/​>​;
        }
        ​return​ (
            ​<​div​>​
                ​<​PageHead
                    links​=​{[{ name​:​ ​"​Login​"​, url​:​ ​"​/login​"​ }]}
                    title​=​"​Login​"​
                ​/​>​
                ​<​section className​=​"​content​"​>​
                    ​<​div className​=​"​container-fluid​"​>​
                        ​<​div className​=​"​row​"​>​
                            ​<​div className​=​"​col-md-12​"​>​
                                {​/*​ <!-- general form elements --> ​*/​}
                                ​<​div className​=​"​card card-success​"​>​
                                    ​<​div className​=​"​card-header​"​>​
                                        ​<​h3 className​=​"​card-title​"​>​
                                            Quick Example
                                        ​<​/​h3​>​
                                    ​<​/​div​>​
                                    {​/*​ <!-- /.card-header -->​
​                                <!-- form start --> ​*/​}
                                    ​<​form onSubmit​=​{​this​.​handleSubmit​}​>​
                                        ​<​div className​=​"​card-body​"​>​
                                            ​<​div className​=​"​form-group​"​>​
                                                ​<​label htmlFor​=​"​exampleInputEmail1​"​>​
                                                    Username
                                                ​<​/​label​>​
                                                ​<​input
                                                    type​=​"​text​"​
                                                    name​=​"​email​"​
                                                    className​=​"​form-control​"​
                                                    id​=​"​exampleInputEmail1​"​
                                                    placeholder​=​"​Enter username​"​
                                                    value​=​{​this​.​state​.​username​}
                                                    onChange​=​{​this​.​handleChange​}
                                                ​/​>​
                                            ​<​/​div​>​
                                            ​<​div className​=​"​form-group​"​>​
                                                ​<​label htmlFor​=​"​exampleInputPassword1​"​>​
                                                    Password
                                                ​<​/​label​>​
                                                ​<​input
                                                    type​=​"​password​"​
                                                    name​=​"​password​"​
                                                    className​=​"​form-control​"​
                                                    id​=​"​exampleInputPassword1​"​
                                                    placeholder​=​"​Password​"​
                                                    value​=​{​this​.​state​.​password​}
                                                    onChange​=​{​this​.​handleChange​}
                                                ​/​>​
                                            ​<​/​div​>​
                                        ​<​/​div​>​
                                        {​/*​ <!-- /.card-body --> ​*/​}

                                        ​<​div className​=​"​card-footer​"​>​
                                            ​<​button
                                                type​=​"​submit​"​
                                                className​=​"​btn btn-primary​"​
                                            ​>​
                                                {​this​.​state​.​loading​
                                                    ​?​ ​"​Loading..​"​
                                                    ​:​ ​"​Login​"​}
                                            ​<​/​button​>​
                                        ​<​/​div​>​
                                    ​<​/​form​>​
                                ​<​/​div​>​
                                {​/*​ <!-- /.card --> ​*/​}
                            ​<​/​div​>​
                        ​<​/​div​>​
                    ​<​/​div​>​
                ​<​/​section​>​
            ​<​/​div​>​
        );
    }
}

​const​ ​mapStateToProps​ ​=​ ({ auth }) ​=>​ {
    ​return​ {
        auth
    };
};

​export​ ​default​ ​connect​(mapStateToProps, { login })(Login);
```

I have no clue how to get it done as I'm new to the React Stack. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated. I look forward to get this solved with the help of powerful community. 
in Login console.log(this.props)
[image]

Comment: can you post the console.log(props)? moreover in your input fied you are using this.state.username whereas your state is "email" and not "username"...

Comment: I have added console.log(props)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, actually there was an issue inside the actionCreator.